# Why is a Polish space a standard measurable space?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, polish-spaces

A measurable space ($\Omega$,$\mathcal F$) is called a standard measurable space if it is Borel isomorphic to one of the following measurable
spaces: $(\langle 1, n\rangle,\mathcal B(\langle 1, n\rangle))$, $(\mathbb N,\mathcal B(\mathbb N))$ or $(M,\mathcal B(M))$, where $\langle 1, n\rangle =
\{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$ with the discrete topology, $\mathbb N = \{1, 2, \ldots \}$ with the discrete topology and $M=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ with the product topology.

Where Borel isomorphic means there exists a bijection which is a measurable mapping.

My question is as follows: Why is a Polish space a standard measurable space??

Comment: This is deep. You are asking for a proof of a basic isomorphism theorem of measure theory. One good reference for this is Measure Theory by Cohn.

Comment: The proof is described in Appendix (Polish Spaces and Standard Borel Spaces) of Takesaki (1979).